# Oracle SQL Time Format

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want a specific time format in Oracle SQL. The format is 2018-05-17T10:15:12-0300. Can anyone help me. I tried this but the last '-0300' is not reflecting in my result

```
Select to_char(systimestamp,'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mm:ss"-Z"') from dual;
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried and the issues with it

Comment: Read about [`TO_CHAR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) and [`DATETIME` format models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the the format model `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM`, for instance

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') FROM DUAL;

2018-06-01T13:04:44+0200
```

The date format models are explained in Oracle's [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA).

Comment: Every Time I Run this query i get 0000 after +. Can you tell me what is the reason for this. For Example - 2018-06-04T08:04:07+0000

Comment: `TZH` is the hours of the time zone, `TZM` the minutes. For instance, my example database is set to `+0200`, for Central European Summer Time, which is [UTC + 2 hours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B02:00). You can check your database with `SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;`

Comment: @hemantsingh Glad to her it! If the answer was ok, you might want to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it, so that everybody else doesn't need to try to look for an answer for it...